# Active Directory get Domain Admins in all sub domains

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

May I know what is the ldap query string to get list of all the Domain Admins? I found that Active Directory has a group called Domain Admin when AD is installed. So, I can query to get all the members of this group. But, I have to provide the DN for this group like *CN=Domain Admins,CN=Users,DC=bar,DC=foo,DC=com*. It gets complicated in case of multiple domains as I have to create the query string for each domain.

Is there a better way to do this? What is the query that I have to run to get all the sub domains?

Answer (score 0):

Query from your forest root with:

`memberOf`: DN of the group which is domain admin. If there is no forest-wide group, perform the step per group in a loop.